# Drawing a graph using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I making some graphs using HTML canvas but I want to draw line with multiple colors, at every point it should change to a new random color,

```
 ctx.moveTo(Ximg+46,Yimg+200);
        for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(js_array[i]=="900"){ctx.strokeStyle = "Grey";}
        else{ctx.lineTo(Ximg+50+i*mul,(Yimg+200)-(js_array[i]*(height/max)));}

        }
```

am gonna change grey to random but the problem is it colors the previous path(line) with grey,i want each piece of line in a different color,is it possible in Javascript?
in OpenGl there was command we used to write to take always the last given color or not,is there  a similar one in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

With the context, the strokeStyle property can take rgba, rgb, and Hexadecimal colors as well as the name of the color.

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + (Math.Random()*255) + "," + (Math.Random()*255) + "," + (Math.Random()*255) + ", 1)";
```

Or perhaps a new function that returns the color, or assigns it.

If that wasn't what you were looking for, could you supply some values for the undeclared variables so that we can test it more thoroughly?